# google apps script spreadsheet string retrieving issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, utf-8, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I can't figure out why the following code isn't working properly in case of special characters:

```
[...]
// get strings (names) from spreadsheet
var persons = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 31, 4).getValues();

// for each row
for (var row in persons) {

    // build the filename
    var myFile = persons[row][1] + "_" + persons[row][0] + "_20180124.txt";

    [...]

    // handle from Google Drive only file             
    var driveFiles = DriveApp.getFilesByName(myFile);
    while (driveFiles.hasNext()) {
        var file = driveFiles.next();

        if(driveFiles.getName() == myFile) {

            /* write to Log

            Saša_KLANJŠČEK_20180124.txt     not written
            Peter_MARINČIČ_20180124.txt     not written
            Peter_KLANJŠČEK_20180124.txt    not written
            Niko_ČERNIC_20180124.txt        not written
            Tjaša_KOGOJ_20180124.txt        written
            */

            Logger.log(myFile + "\n");

        [...]
```

Strings with uppercase unicode characters causes the conditional statement to fail. I tried with toString("UTF-8") method, but it still doesn't work. Is it an encoding problem?

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean with "fail". Any error message? If yes, add it to the question. 

Whats the output of `console.log(driveFiles.getName())` for every file?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`if(driveFiles.getName() == myFile) {`

into

```
 if(file.getName() == myFile) {
```